# hyperledger-composer v1.1:unable to instantiate chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am currently working on hyperLedger composer v1.1 and am following the tutorials. I managed to install the chaincode onto the network however it fails at instantiation.Can somebody tell me why? Any help is appreciated.

Command:

composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-common failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-04T13_04_07_240Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the chaincode build, Fabric does an `npm install`. Looks like you're behind a proxy (`npm install` not being able to access https://registry.npmjs.org/ suggests you're behind a proxy and therefore it can't resolve the URL above (to pull down a Composer npm module/dependency during install)).  So you would need to provide an `npmrc` file - in the `composer network install` command sequence - so that it can configure the behaviour of the npm install - and access a known registry, like https://registry.npmjs.org/ . See more information on this here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information . Example usage is: `composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a digitalproperty-network.bna -o npmrcFile=/home/user1/config/npmConfig`