# Unable to start hyperledger fabric network with hyperledger composer

Tags: npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am currently working on `HyperLedger composer v1.1` on `Ubuntu` *Virtual Machine* (`16.04 LTS`) hosted in remote server and using VMWare Vsphere client to connect to that host machine. My PC (*Windows 7*) and the hosting server are in the same LAN.

In fact, I am following the tutorial (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial).

1. I managed to install the chaincode onto the network but when I tried to start the business network using the command :

   ```
   composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
   ```

   I got this `error` :

   ```
   ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
   npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
   npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-runtime-hlfv1 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443 ...."
   ```
2. Then, when I saw the suggestion of `@PaulO'Mahony` at "[hyperledger-composer v1.1:unable to instantiate chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652193/hyperledger-composer-v1-1unable-to-instantiate-chaincode?rq=1)" 
   I tried to locate the npmrc file but it was not there then I did as `@oligofren` suggested at [Node .npmrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877722/node-npmrc-file).
3. After that, I have executed this command :

   ```
   composer network install --c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --a tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna -o npmrcFile=/home/user1/.npmrc"
   ```

   where `".npmrc"` file is generated after I have logged in (using npm login).
4. Finally, when try to execute the above command "composer network start...." the same error is still exist !!!

Note that : I have executed `"./stopFabric.sh"`, `"./teardownFabric.sh"` and then `"./startFabric.sh"` before I did each solution!

Comment: Have a look at the first link here about Composer Network Install - it shows how to create a temporary container to test npm installs: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cinstallissues 

Then maybe look at this 2nd link in the knowledge wiki about composer network start: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#startissues

Comment: I followed the above solutions but still have the same issue!!!