# Why I'm getting this issue while I'm trying to start my custom network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

While I'm working on Hyperledger Composer v0.19 I created 'tutorial-network', installed and started it as in the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial). There was no problem. But I tried to create my custom network. While I was trying to start my custom network I got this issue;

```
    Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-common failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-10T11_49_13_667Z-debug.log
"
Command failed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this section of the Composer Knowledge Wiki: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cinstallissues

Comment: I saw that section. It is talking about an npmrcFile option for install network command but I haven't any npmrc file or I don't know where is it? Should I create that file myself? If true what should be content of this file? I don't know anything about it.

Comment: yes, create... see the docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information and also the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652193/hyperledger-composer-v1-1unable-to-instantiate-chaincode?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest you also research the meaning of EAI_AGAIN error code and look into understanding docker networking as well.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm not getting this error while I was deploying the 'tutorial-network'? Processes are the same for both examples.

Comment: My both network examples are on the same machine and has been created over the same internet connection. No different machine or different internet connection. I'm using Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.22 and Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `composer network start` command uses Fabric under the covers to build a "Docker Chaincode Container" for your Business Network.  During that build there are `npm install` commands running and they are the commands generating the error you see.  So the new container can't connect to registry.npmjs.org

It is possible that there were network problems when you tried, and if you try again it *may* work.  It is slightly strange that you were able to work through the Tutorial Network OK, but your Custom Network does not work - are you using the same machine for the Custom Network, and connected to the same network?  (did you run the tutorial from an 'open' home network and are now trying custom on a Corporate/Organisational network with a proxy?)

The npmrc file is a set of configurations for npm which can include proxy details, and in the case oc Composer, you can pass the file into the new Chaincode Container so that it can connect the npm registry, or some shadow repository that you use.

There are lots of other Stack Overflow posts about npm and npmrc (and other resources on the net.)

Even though it is the `composer network start` command that shows the errors, the npmrc file has to be specified on the `composer network install` command.

Comment: OK. I got it but is there any example of npmrc file? I don't know what kind of contents an npmrc file contains? I couldn't find any example of it.